# UIImageView linking to URL when tapped

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have some sort of image-slider to show some promotions images ('promo's). I used a snippet I found somewhere around here. It works by populating a scrollView with UIImageViews with frames and uses the UIScrollViewDelegate methods and PageControl methods to move left and right. This is the part of the code that sets up the page:

```
-(void)setupPage{
    [scrollView setDelegate:self];
    [self.scrollView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    [scrollView setCanCancelContentTouches:NO];

    scrollView.indicatorStyle = UIScrollViewIndicatorStyleWhite;
    scrollView.clipsToBounds = YES;
    scrollView.scrollEnabled = YES;
    scrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;

    //cargar fotos
    CGFloat cx = 0;
    for (id row in promosArray) {
        NSLog(@"imagen %@", [row url]);
        UIImage *image = [row foto];
        //image = [image imageRotatedByDegrees:90.0f];
        UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
        CGRect rect = imageView.frame;
        rect.size.height = image.size.height;
        rect.size.width = image.size.width;
        rect.origin.x = ((scrollView.frame.size.width - image.size.width) / 2) + cx;
        rect.origin.y = ((scrollView.frame.size.height - image.size.height) / 2);

        imageView.frame = rect;
        [imageView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];

        [scrollView addSubview:imageView];
        cx += scrollView.frame.size.width;
    }
    self.pageControl.numberOfPages = [promosArray count];
    [scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(cx, [scrollView bounds].size.height)];

    [cargando setHidden:YES];
    [scrollView setHidden:NO];
    [pageControl setHidden:NO];

}
```

I take the info from promosArray, wich is an array of objects of type `promo` with this header

```
@interface Promo : NSObject
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIImage *foto;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSURL *url;

-(id) initWithUIImage: (UIImage *) f andNSURL: (NSURL *) u;
@end
```

So promo is just an object to hold both the UIImage it should show and the URL it links to when tapped.

So my question is how do I make that the UIImages, when 'touched up inside' open a safari window with the corresponding URL?
I tried adding a button with the same frame as a subview, and I only got 1 button (or them all in the same place)

The think that complicates me the most is linking each button with it's correspondent URL.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider making your foto it's own class that inherits from UIImageView.

This way you can set it up just as you did in your iterator but also hand in the NSUrl (making it the foto's responsibility not the client code). Not only that you can then extend the logic of this new (F)oto class by adding a UITapGestureRecognizer automagically and have it respond to the user by opening up the safari window.

Comment: I was considering inheriting from UIImageView. The part of the UITapGestureRecognizer is what's bothering me. because touching is such a fine thing, I'll never be capable of processing a tap as good as the UIButton does. (Somebody else said this in a comment of a similar topic) That's why I think I rather have a imageView with a button over it.

Comment: You should be able to use the UIGestureRecognizerState UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded to get the touches up feel. You can decide to get a bit more complex and subclass from a UIView that will bridge the image creation and create a UIbutton for you (the UIView being the parent class that will hold the image and button inside of its bounds). Same as above but now with a button and a bit more work. Definitely worth considering to keep the logic encapsulated.

Comment: Finally ended up using the UITapGestureRecognizer. I had a problem with using two frames, I was "moving" the wrong one, that's why the buttons didn't work. Thank you for your help!